# can I turn off the "cleanTask" on flyway in production environments

Tags: flyway

I am looking to be able to turn off the ability to execute the "CleanTask" (com.googlecode.flyway.ant.cleanTask) in a production environment so that our production database cannot be inadvertently dropped.

Is there a way to do this?

GD

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this out of the box.

One solution could be to wrap the Flyway tasks and provide a no-op for clean instead of delegating to the real implementation.

Comment: What about Maven? Is it possible to prevent execution of clean goal if production profile is in effect?